# How to Implement Spinner with key-value in Android?

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I want to use Spinner with key-value pair. UI shows KEY, and get selected i get VALUE.

So i use HashMap ,

```
String name[] = { "Btech", "Mtech", "Bca", "Mca" };
String id[] = { "111", "222", "333", "444" };

HashMap<String, String> spinnerMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

 for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
        spinnerMap.put(name[i], id[i]);
    }

ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String,   String>>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

adapter.add(spinnerMap);

spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

But it is showing

```
{Btech=111,Mtech=222,Bca=333,Mca=444}
```

Comment: create custom class, extends of HashMap and override toString method and return what ever you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's using the toString method of HashMap to display the value. So it sees this as one object being in the spinner.

There are two ways to do this:

1. Implement an extension to ArrayAdapter and override the getView() method to return the appropriate value.
2. Implement your own Object to fill the spinner and override its toString method.

The first method has preference, because it allows for much more flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Spinner spinner= (Spinner) 
        .findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = yourList;

SimpleAdapter arrayAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(mContext, list,
        R.layout.spinner_item2, new String[] { SystemGlobal.CODE,
                SystemGlobal.DESCRIPTION }, new int[] { R.id.txv_code,
                R.id.txv_description });

spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

spinner
        .setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                    View view, int position, long id) {
                String desc = ((TextView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.txv_description)).getText()
                        .toString();
                String code = ((TextView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.txv_code)).getText()
                        .toString();

                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Code: "+code+", Desc: "+ desc, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });




  xml file:
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

  <TextView
android:id="@+id/txv_code"
style="@style/textview_style"
android:layout_width="1dip"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:visibility="gone" />

 <TextView
  android:id="@+id/txv_description"
  style="@style/textview_style"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:padding="@dimen/spinner_item_padding" />

  </LinearLayout>
```